# TTFB - Track run time on php functions

Tags: php, debugging, benchmarking

I need to track the php functions run time to locate Time to First Byte problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two major options:

1. [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler), one of the best PHP debuggers out there, suitable for running in a dev environment.
2. [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof), a tool designed by the Facebook folks, suitable for running on both dev and production servers. [More docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php)

Both of these will let you gather performance metrics on your script, including how much time is spent inside each native PHP function.

Comment: You can use e.g. [kCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) on Linux or [WinCacheGrind](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) on Windows, to visualize the xdebug dump file. They are great programs for profiling your code.